# Chart JS displaying data in a wrong manner

Tags: chart.js

So I am using the chart js library and experiencing issues with the chart. For some of the months I do not have data, this means that the chart is filling out the chart from january to whatever month depending on the data instead of putting in the data at the right month.

An example of the data I have:

{Period: '2021-11-01T00:00:00', AverageConversationEval: 4}

{Period: '2022-03-01T00:00:00', AverageConversationEval: 5}

{Period: '2022-05-01T00:00:00', AverageConversationEval: 3}

{Period: '2022-06-01T00:00:00', AverageConversationEval: 1.5}

{Period: '2022-07-01T00:00:00', AverageConversationEval: 4}

So here it's filling the chart from november till march instead of making empty holes in the graph.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to this discussion: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/discussions/10659

Comment: Tried using the solution that was suggested. Does not seem to work (at least not in my particular case).

Comment: maybe a reproducible sample could help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.